# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline is not minifying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Im upgrading my app to rails31 .. everything works quite ok but i have a problem with the asset pipeline. im using rails3.1.rc5

My js and my css gets combined but not minified..
Im using:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

to precompile the assets..

I have these settings in my production.rb

```
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :scss
```

The files are combined and get the md5 in the name but they are not minified.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This solved my problem....

http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/4bc7bac8b295b3aa

Comment: Can you explain a little? did you remove the setting from your application.rb or did you modify your apache config?

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUP=assets assets:precompile
```